# JavaScript: Trying to find the deepest nested child node in DOM

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, nodes

I have been presented a problem for a bootcamp prep course. The problem is stated as follows:

***Define a function deepestChild() that pulls out the most deeply nested child element from div#grand-node***

My code so far:

HTML:

```
    <main id="app">
      <ul class="unranked-list">
        <li>2</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="ranked-list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="ranked-list">
        <li>12</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>

      <div id="nested">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div class="target">
                1
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="grand-node">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                boo!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deepestChild(){
 let element = document.getElementById('grand-node');
  while(element.hasChildNodes()){
    element = element.firstChild;
  }
  return element;
}
```

This is the error I get from the testing platform:
*AssertionError: expected { Object () } to equal { Object () }*

Unfortunately that doesn't provide much information. I have tested the loop and for some reason it doesn't run through all the cycles so I think it is a problem with finding the children. I don't think it is finding the firstChild. I'm stumped right now. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. By the parameters of the problem the solution has to be in Vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Your best bet here, by far, is to step through that code in the debugger built into your browser or IDE. That will let you see the value of `element` as it changes and follow what your code is doing.

Comment: The problem with your code is that it only goes down the first branch of the tree, which isn't the deepest branch. You have to traverse the entire tree to know which the deepest branch is, which will involve counting how many times you've gone into a child node and remembering the element at the deepest level (so far) as you continue to search.

Comment: let element = document.getElementById('grand-node');
  var innertext = element.lastElementChild.innerText;